# Mass update in laravel using foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How to Update mass records without deleting or replacing old one inserted records. Here mine problem is that last inserted record will replace with latest records.

```
/*DB::table('syllabuses')
             ->where('course_id', $curse_id)
             ->Where('semster',$semesterid)
             ->delete();*/
               $Syllabus =   Syllabus::find($id);
                foreach ($data as $value) 
                {  
                    //$Syllabus =  new Syllabus;//
                     $Syllabus->slno = $value->SlNo;
                      $Syllabus->coursecode =$value->cousrecode;
                     $Syllabus->coursename =$value->coursename;
                     $Syllabus->credit =$value->credit;
                     $Syllabus->papertype=$value->papertype;
                     $Syllabus->deptoffering_name=$value->Deptoffer;
                     $Syllabus->deptoffering_id=$value->Department;
                     $Syllabus->dept_id = $details['depart'];
                     $Syllabus->save();

                }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to update syllabus records given a set of syllabus ids?

Comment: can you please explain it proper what you want to do and please add whole code so we can understand better

Comment: yeah I want to update syllabus ids

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the difference between INSERT and UPDATE first. Definitely update query replace the old values of the relevant record. In your query you are tying updating same "Syllabus".

```
$Syllabus = Syllabus::find($id);
    foreach ($data as $value) 
        {  
           //$Syllabus =  new Syllabus;//
             $Syllabus->slno = $value->SlNo;
             $Syllabus->coursecode =$value->cousrecode;
             $Syllabus->coursename =$value->coursename;
             $Syllabus->credit =$value->credit;
             $Syllabus->papertype=$value->papertype;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_name=$value->Deptoffer;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_id=$value->Department;
             $Syllabus->dept_id = $details['depart'];
             $Syllabus->save();

         }
```

In above code, you find the Syllabus outside of the foreach. Then you update the that found record inside the foreach. If you want to update many "Syllabus", then try this:

```
foreach ($data as $value) 
        {  
             $Syllabus = Syllabus::find("SyllabusID");
             $Syllabus->slno = $value->SlNo;
             $Syllabus->coursecode =$value->cousrecode;
             $Syllabus->coursename =$value->coursename;
             $Syllabus->credit =$value->credit;
             $Syllabus->papertype=$value->papertype;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_name=$value->Deptoffer;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_id=$value->Department;
             $Syllabus->dept_id = $details['depart'];
             $Syllabus->save();

         }
```

Or else, if you want to remain old records, please try to create new records in db  using following code

```
foreach ($data as $value) 
        {  
             $Syllabus = new Syllabus();
             $Syllabus->slno = $value->SlNo;
             $Syllabus->coursecode =$value->cousrecode;
             $Syllabus->coursename =$value->coursename;
             $Syllabus->credit =$value->credit;
             $Syllabus->papertype=$value->papertype;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_name=$value->Deptoffer;
             $Syllabus->deptoffering_id=$value->Department;
             $Syllabus->dept_id = $details['depart'];
             $Syllabus->save();

         }
```

Read official laravel documentation for further details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent